# Getting the sum after multiple AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHM4t/3/).

I've used .when().done() method to get the values of Facebook likes and github followers but the problem is when I sum these two values I'm getting

```
[object Object],success,[object Object][object Object],success,[object Object]
```

***Jquery***

```
    $(function () {
    $.when(
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/bloggerever",
        success: function (data) {
            var githubfollowercount =data.followers;
          $(".githubfollowercount").html(githubfollowercount);
        }
    }),
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://graph.facebook.com/bloggerever",
        success: function (data) {
            var facebookfollowcount = data.likes;
 $(".facebookfollowercount").html(facebookfollowcount);
        }

    })).done(function (githubfollowercount, facebookfollowcount) {
       var total=facebookfollowcount + githubfollowercount;

        $('.totalfollowercount').append(total);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're trying to add two objects but it coerces them as strings. Try `console.log`ing the results and see what you get - my bet is: not numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the same response object as in the ajax call, but in `then()` they are wrapped in  arrays so you have to first access the first member in the array, then the property that contains the likes / followers etc

```
).done(function (git, fb) {
    var total = git[0].followers + fb[0].likes;
    $('.totalfollowercount').append(total);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kHM4t/6/)

Answer (score 2):

For one, the callback parameters of a [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) promise are arguments `Array`s when the single promises resolve with multiple values, in the case of an ajax request `[data, status, jqXHR]`.

For second, they contain the original `data`, not the one from the variable that you used in the single `done` callbacks.

Do this:

```
$(function () {
    $.when(
        $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/bloggerever").then(function(data) {
            return data.followers;
        }).done(function(githubfollowercount) {
            $(".githubfollowercount").html(githubfollowercount);
        }),
        $.getJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/bloggerever").then(function(data) {
            return data.likes;
        }).done(function(facebookfollowcount) {
            $(".facebookfollowercount").html(facebookfollowcount);
        })
    ).done(function (twitterfollowercount, instagramfollowercount) {
        var total=instagramfollowercount + twitterfollowercount;
        $('.totalfollowercount').append(total);
    });
});
```

([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHM4t/7/))